# Complicated SOQL SELECT

Tags: apex, soql, inner-join, outer-join

I have the following data model:
[image]

Now I would like to do the following:

> By knowing `zced__Interaction__c` extract all the `zced__Assessment__c`.
>
> Then for each of the extracted `zced__Assessment__c` I would like to extract all the `zced__Assessment_Question__c` with the following fields (the fields actually do not matter in the case I suppose) `zced__Question_text__c` and `zced__Question_Instruction__c`.
>
> At the same time for each extracted `zced__Question_Instruction__c` I would like to extract all `zced__Assessment_Answer__c` with the following fields (the fields here do not matter as well I think) `zced__Answer_Text__c`, `zced__Is_Correct__c`, `zced__Answer_Points__c`.

So, after reading [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) post I come up with the following solution (which does not work and I do not know how to fix it):

```
    SELECT (
SELECT zced__Question_text__c, zced__Question_Instruction__c,
                    (
                            SELECT zced__Answer_Text__c, zced__Is_Correct__c, zced__Answer_Points__c
                            FROM zced__Assessment_Answer__c
                    )
                    FROM zced__Assessment_Question__c
                )
                FROM zced__Assessment__c
                WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
```

What am I doing wrong here? The `interactionId` is checked to be correct.

I am stuck while trying to implement the first step of the solution:

> first query at the `zced__Assessment__c level`

```
List<sObject> l = [
            SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM zced__Assessment_Question__c)
            FROM zced__Assessment__c
            WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
        ];
```

It does not allow to query it this way. Why?

Comment: What is your exact use case or whats the functionality you want to achieve?

Comment: @SantanuBoral, I have an interaction on the front-end. And I would like to extract all assessment related data about the interaction from the back-end. I assure you that there is no `x-y problem`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SOQL parent-child queries only support [one level of relationship descent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm):

> In each specified relationship, only one level of parent-to-child relationship can be specified in a query. For example, if the FROM clause specifies Account, the SELECT clause can specify only the Contact or other objects at that level. It could not specify a child object of Contact.

The only way you'll be able to do this in a single query is to have the base query object be `zced__Assessment_Question__c`, filtering on `zced__Assessment__r.zced__Interaction__c`. That would allow you to pull in the fields you need from Assessment while also performing a parent-child query against Assessment Answer.

However, that approach may not meet your needs, because you're going to get back a `List<zced__Assessment_Question__c>` and have to postprocess in Apex to get back to a `List<zced__Assessment__c>`. It may be best to break this into two parent-child queries: first query at the `zced__Assessment__c` level, then iterate to gather the `zced__Assessment_Question__c` Ids in a Set, then perform a parent-child query against `zced__Assessment_Question__c` to get its children.

You can populate the latter query results in an `Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c>` by doing

```
Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c> childMap = new Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c>(
    [SELECT zced__Question_text__c, zced__Question_Instruction__c,
            (
                 SELECT zced__Answer_Text__c, zced__Is_Correct__c, zced__Answer_Points__c
                 FROM zced__Assessment_Answer__c
            )
     FROM zced__Assessment_Question__c
     WHERE Id IN :questionIdSet]
);
```

The Map will then allow easy access to the grandchild records as you iterate over the children of each `zced__Assessment__c` from your top-level query.

Note that any time you perform a SOQL parent-child query, you must query the child by the [relationship name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects), *not* by its own API name. For standard objects, this is often the plural of the child object name (`SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account`), while with custom objects and relationships it will often, but not always, be the plural child object name with `__r` instead of `__c`. Make sure to refer to the lookup or master-detail field itself to find the relationship name.

Comment: If you could, help me, please to tackle the your solution implementation issue. I updated the question.

Comment: See the new last paragraph of my answer for more on this.

Comment: For custom it is often the *pluralized* child object name plus __r.