# What to use instead of n-dimensional List in Apex?

Tags: apex, data

I have the following data model:

[image]

My purpose is to get all the needed data from the server-side on the client side. And I need to know: all the assessments, for each assessment I need to know questions which are related to it, for each question I need to know all the related answers. And for both questions and assessments I may need a few fields (for example, for a question in addition to a list of answers I need a question text and question directions).

I am using guides provided in [the](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224984/complicated-soql-select) answer to retrieve the data using SOQL.

Here is what my request looks so far:

```
List<zced__Assessment__c> assessmentAndQuestions = [
            SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM zced__Assessment_Questions__r)
            FROM zced__Assessment__c
            WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
        ];

        Set<String> questions = new Set<String>();
        Map<String, List<String>> assessmentToQuestions = new Map<String, List<String>>();
        for(zced__Assessment__c assessment: assessmentAndQuestions) {
            assessmentToQuestions.put(assessment.Id, new List<String>());
            for(zced__Assessment_Question__c question: assessment.zced__Assessment_Questions__r) {
                assessmentToQuestions.get(assessment.Id).add(question.Id);
                questions.add(question.Id);
            }
        }

        Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c> questionToAnswers = new Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c> ([
            SELECT zced__Question_text__c, zced__Question_Instruction__c,
            (
                SELECT zced__Answer_Text__c, zced__Is_Correct__c, zced__Answer_Points__c
                FROM zced__Assessment_Answers__r
            )
            FROM zced__Assessment_Question__c
            WHERE Id IN :questions
        ]);
```

As you can see I gathered all the needed data and now it comes to assembling the data into a data structure and sending it to the client-side.

So, what I was able to come up with is the following:

> I would have a `List<List<List<List<SObject>>>> res;`. Where `res[q][w][e+d]` would mean the data about the e-th answer which is in w-th question in q-th assessment. While the objects `res[q][w][e]`, `res[q][w][e+1]`, ..., `res[q][w][e+d]` would hold a w-th question`s in q-th assessment fields which I will need on the client side.

I am feeling that my solution is very clumsy. Are there different approaches to solving such kinds of problems?

Here is my code after the answer was provided:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static QuizDataNode retrieveQuizInfo(String interactionId) {
        QuizDataNode res = new QuizDataNode(null);

        List<zced__Assessment__c> assessmentAndQuestions = [
            SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM zced__Assessment_Questions__r)
            FROM zced__Assessment__c
            WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
        ];

        Set<String> questions = new Set<String>();
        Map<String, List<String>> assessmentToQuestions = new Map<String, List<String>>();
        for(zced__Assessment__c assessment: assessmentAndQuestions) {
            assessmentToQuestions.put(assessment.Id, new List<String>());
            for(zced__Assessment_Question__c question: assessment.zced__Assessment_Questions__r) {
                assessmentToQuestions.get(assessment.Id).add(question.Id);
                questions.add(question.Id);
            }
        }

        Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c> questionToAnswers = new Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c> ([
            SELECT zced__Question_text__c, zced__Question_Instruction__c,
            (
                SELECT zced__Answer_Text__c, zced__Is_Correct__c, zced__Answer_Points__c
                FROM zced__Assessment_Answers__r
            )
            FROM zced__Assessment_Question__c
            WHERE Id IN :questions
        ]);

        for(zced__Assessment__c e: [
            SELECT Id
            FROM zced__Assessment__c
            WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
        ]) {
            QuizDataNode qdn = new QuizDataNode(new zced__Assessment__c(Id = e.Id));
            for(String f: assessmentToQuestions.get(e.Id)) {
                qdn.addChild(new QuizDataNode(questionToAnswers.get(f)));
            }
            res.addChild(qdn);
        }

        return res;
    }


public class QuizDataNode {
    @AuraEnabled
    public SObject sob {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public QuizDataNode parent {get; private set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<QuizDataNode> children {get; private set;}

    public QuizDataNode(SObject sob) {
        this.sob = sob;
        children = new List<QuizDataNode>();
    }

    public void addChild(QuizDataNode child) {
        children.add(child);
        child.parent = this;
    }
}
```

When I call the method on the client-side it returns with a state of an `ERROR`. And here is what it tells me:

`message`:

> "Communication error, please retry or reload the page"

`stack`:

> Error: Communication error, please retry or reload the page
>           at U.z.oh (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:587:435)
>           at Object.onXHRReceived (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/libraries/instrumentation/idleDetector/idleDetector.js:2:265)
>           at Object.TA.Ak (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:240:255)
>           at UG.xp (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:835:421)
>           at Object.TA.Ak (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:240:255)
>           at TA.start (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:239:313)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.e (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:577:103)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to think of this as a tree where each parent has multiple children. You can create a wrapper class or multiple wrapper classes to model that relationship where the wrapper also holds a reference to the specific SObject.

I’m using my phone so too painful to add example code but hope this helps a bit.

**PS**

The code would look something like this:

```
public class Node {

    public SObject sob {get; set;}

    public Node parent {get; private set;}
    public Node[] children {get; private set;}

    public Node(SObject sob) {
        this.sob = sob;
        children = new Node[] {};
    }

    public void addChild(Node child) {
        children.add(child);
        child.parent = this;
    }
}
```

and to build the tree:

```
Node root = new Node(null);
for (...) {
    Node assessment = new Node(assessmentSob);
    root.addhild(assessment);
    for (...) {
        Node question = new Node(questionSob);
        assessment.addChild(question);
        for (...) {
            Node answer = new Node(answerSob);
            question.addChild(answer);
        }
    }
}
```

The `sob` can be cast to the appropriate type.

Comment: Yes, I am not very clear what you are talking about here. So, it would be nice to see maybe a schema drawn (of if it is easier some code provided).

Comment: @iloveseven what Keith means is that you can create a class which wraps a certain list of another class which wraps another. Kind of like the Matryoshka dolls. It's not the cleanest of codes, but Apex can't do much better imo.

Comment: Should I return `root` to the client-side part? Or are there a better way to return the result?

Comment: @iloveseven I'd return the root but alternatively you could add a getter that returns the root's list and return that.

Comment: Could you, please check the question. I updated it to ask about some implementation issues.

Comment: @iloveseven Turn on the server-side logging and you should see a more explicit error. If you can't solve the problem yourself after a couple of hours, create a separate question that contains only the relevant detail (and link back to this question).