# Can not return a custom Apex class from the server side to the client side

Tags: apex, soql, lightning

I can not return a custom Apex class from the server side to the client side.

Here is the class:

```
public class QuizDataNode {
    @AuraEnabled
    public SObject sob {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public QuizDataNode parent {get; private set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<QuizDataNode> children {get; private set;}

    public QuizDataNode(SObject sob) {
        this.sob = sob;
        children = new List<QuizDataNode>();
    }

    public void addChild(QuizDataNode child) {
        children.add(child);
        child.parent = this;
    }
}
```

Here is the function which is returning the class instance:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static QuizDataNode retrieveQuizInfo(String interactionId) {
        QuizDataNode res = new QuizDataNode(null);

        List<zced__Assessment__c> assessmentAndQuestions = [
            SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM zced__Assessment_Questions__r)
            FROM zced__Assessment__c
            WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
        ];

        System.debug('assessmentAndQuestions: ' + assessmentAndQuestions);

        Set<String> questions = new Set<String>();
        Map<String, List<String>> assessmentToQuestions = new Map<String, List<String>>();
        for(zced__Assessment__c assessment: assessmentAndQuestions) {
            assessmentToQuestions.put(assessment.Id, new List<String>());
            for(zced__Assessment_Question__c question: assessment.zced__Assessment_Questions__r) {
                assessmentToQuestions.get(assessment.Id).add(question.Id);
                questions.add(question.Id);
            }
        }

        System.debug('questions: ' + questions);
        System.debug('assessmentToQuestions: ' + assessmentToQuestions);

        Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c> questionToAnswers = new Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c> ([
            SELECT zced__Question_text__c, zced__Question_Instruction__c,
            (
                SELECT zced__Answer_Text__c, zced__Is_Correct__c, zced__Answer_Points__c
                FROM zced__Assessment_Answers__r
            )
            FROM zced__Assessment_Question__c
            WHERE Id IN :questions
        ]);

        System.debug('questionToAnswers: ' + questionToAnswers);

        for(zced__Assessment__c e: [
            SELECT Id
            FROM zced__Assessment__c
            WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
        ]) {
            QuizDataNode qdn = new QuizDataNode(new zced__Assessment__c(Id = e.Id));
            for(String f: assessmentToQuestions.get(e.Id)) {
                qdn.addChild(new QuizDataNode(questionToAnswers.get(f)));
            }
            res.addChild(qdn);
        }

        System.debug('res: ' + res);

        return res;
    }
```

Here is the error I am getting on the client side.

`message`:

> Communication error, please retry or reload the page

`stack`:

> Error: Communication error, please retry or reload the page
>       at U.z.oh (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:587:435)
>       at Object.onXHRReceived (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/libraries/instrumentation/idleDetector/idleDetector.js:2:265)
>       at Object.TA.Ak (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:240:255)
>       at UG.xp (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:835:421)
>       at Object.TA.Ak (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:240:255)
>       at TA.start (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:239:313)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.e (https://zeddev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/M8mitrSnSoFe6Y855DnNgg/aura_prod.js:577:103)

Here are the related questions: [1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225086/what-to-use-instead-of-n-dimensional-list-in-apex), [2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224984/complicated-soql-select).

There are no errors in the log in Developer Console and the `System.debug` output is as I expect it.

When I replaced the function code with the following, no error was caught and `System.debug` logs remained correct :

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static QuizDataNode retrieveQuizInfo(String interactionId) {
        QuizDataNode res = new QuizDataNode(null);
        try{

        List<zced__Assessment__c> assessmentAndQuestions = [
            SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM zced__Assessment_Questions__r)
            FROM zced__Assessment__c
            WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
        ];

        System.debug('assessmentAndQuestions: ' + assessmentAndQuestions);

        Set<String> questions = new Set<String>();
        Map<String, List<String>> assessmentToQuestions = new Map<String, List<String>>();
        for(zced__Assessment__c assessment: assessmentAndQuestions) {
            assessmentToQuestions.put(assessment.Id, new List<String>());
            for(zced__Assessment_Question__c question: assessment.zced__Assessment_Questions__r) {
                assessmentToQuestions.get(assessment.Id).add(question.Id);
                questions.add(question.Id);
            }
        }

        System.debug('questions: ' + questions);
        System.debug('assessmentToQuestions: ' + assessmentToQuestions);

        Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c> questionToAnswers = new Map<Id, zced__Assessment_Question__c> ([
            SELECT zced__Question_text__c, zced__Question_Instruction__c,
            (
                SELECT zced__Answer_Text__c, zced__Is_Correct__c, zced__Answer_Points__c
                FROM zced__Assessment_Answers__r
            )
            FROM zced__Assessment_Question__c
            WHERE Id IN :questions
        ]);

        System.debug('questionToAnswers: ' + questionToAnswers);

        for(zced__Assessment__c e: [
            SELECT Id
            FROM zced__Assessment__c
            WHERE zced__Interaction__c = :interactionId
        ]) {
            QuizDataNode qdn = new QuizDataNode(new zced__Assessment__c(Id = e.Id));
            for(String f: assessmentToQuestions.get(e.Id)) {
                qdn.addChild(new QuizDataNode(questionToAnswers.get(f)));
            }
            res.addChild(qdn);
        }

        System.debug('res: ' + res);

         }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e);
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Here is the output of `System.debug` calls:

> 15:20:23.20 (28726380)|USER_DEBUG|[350]|DEBUG|assessmentAndQuestions: (zced__Assessment__c:{Id=a031r00000VnN99AAF}, zced__Assessment__c:{Id=a031r00000VoWMqAAN})
>
> 15:20:23.20 (30114132)|USER_DEBUG|[362]|DEBUG|questions: {a041r00000ZoDZ8AAN}
>
> 15:20:23.20 (30210168)|USER_DEBUG|[363]|DEBUG|assessmentToQuestions: {a031r00000VnN99AAF=(a041r00000ZoDZ8AAN), a031r00000VoWMqAAN=()}
>
> 15:20:23.20 (35403476)|USER_DEBUG|[375]|DEBUG|questionToAnswers: {a041r00000ZoDZ8AAN=zced__Assessment_Question__c:{zced__Question_text__c=gnfgn, zced__Question_Instruction__c=zgnfgn, Id=a041r00000ZoDZ8AAN}}
>
> 15:20:23.20 (39762297)|USER_DEBUG|[389]|DEBUG|res: QuizDataNode:[children=(QuizDataNode:[children=(QuizDataNode:[children=(), parent=(already output), sob=zced__Assessment_Question__c:{zced__Question_text__c=gnfgn, zced__Question_Instruction__c=zgnfgn, Id=a041r00000ZoDZ8AAN}]), parent=(already output), sob=zced__Assessment__c:{Id=a031r00000VnN99AAF}], QuizDataNode:[children=(), parent=(already output), sob=zced__Assessment__c:{Id=a031r00000VoWMqAAN}]), parent=null, sob=null]

Comment: Can you try to put your code in try-catch block and then see the debug logs in the catch block. I think there could be a null pointer exception in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you ran into a JSON serialization error. The hint here is the `(already output)` debug statement. This means that JSON is going to infinitely recurse through the structure until it reaches a maximum depth and then fail. JSON, the protocol, *cannot handle recursive structures*. You should exclude the "parent" option and calculate that on the client after receiving the data.

---

Besides reading the protocol, you can open up your favorite JavaScript environment (e.g. a Developer Console or NodeJS) and try the following:

```
var x = {};
x.parent = x;
JSON.stringify(x);
```

You'll get a Circular Reference error. Internally, this is the same thing that's happening when Lightning tries to process your recursive data structure.

Comment: Oh! It seems clear for me now. So, the deletion of the `parent` field should tackle the issue I hope. Thank you.